# Basic friend timeline algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithm, google-app-engine

I'm sure a lot of services online today must perform a task similar to what I'm doing. A user has friends, and I want to get all status updates of all the user's friends after their friends last status update date.

That was a mouthful, but here's what I have:

A user has say 10 friends. What I want to do is get new status updates for all his friends. So, I prepare a dictionary with each friend's last status date. Something like:

```
for friend in user:
    dictionary['userId] = friend.id
    dictionary['lastDate'] = friend.mostRecentStatusUpdate.date
```

Then, on my server side, I do something like this:

```
for dict in friends:
    userId = dict['userId]
    lastDate = dict['lastDate']
    # each get below, however, launches an RPC and does a separate table lookup, so if I have 100 friends, this seems extremely inefficient
    get statusUpdates for userId where postDate > lastDate
```

The problem with the above approach is that on the server side each iteration of the for loop launches a new query, which launches an RPC. So if there are a lot of friends, it would seem to be really inefficient.

Is there a better way to design my structure to make this task more efficient? How does say Twitter do something like that, where it gets new time line updates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the high level, I'd suggest you follow the prescribed app-engine mantra - make writes expensive to make reads cheap.

For each friend, you should keep a collection of known friends and their last status updates. This will allow you to update friends at write time. This is expensive for the write, but saves you processing and querying at read. This also assumes that you read more than you write.

Additionally, if you are just trying to display N number of latest updates for each friend, I would suggest you use [NDB Structured property](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#structured) to store the Friend objects - this way you can create matching data structure. As part of the object, create a collection of keys that correspond to the status updates. When the status update is written, add to the collection, and potentially remove older entries (if space is a concern).

This way when you need to retrieve the updates, you are getting them by key, instead of a more expensive query types.

An alternative to this that avoids any additional queries, is to keep the entire update instead of just keys. However, this will be a lot bigger for storage - 10 friends all interconnected, means 100 versions of the same update.

Comment: I'm not understanding what you mean by "This will allow you to update friends at write time.".. So say I have known friends and their last updates..how would this help me get their new updates, at least more efficiently than before?

Comment: So you're saying when a user makes a status update, he should add that status update to all his friend's collection as well?

Comment: Also, it's not really last N updates that I'll need, but rather "all updates with create date newer than last status date"

Comment: Basically, what I'm suggesting you do is write the keys for the updates you want to retrieve to all friends of a user. This removes your first for loop and replaces the second for loop with much faster queries. Can you please clarify "all updates with create date newer than last status date" - which status date?

Comment: Well I don't want to retrieve status updates that I already have. So I get the date of the last status update I already have, and make sure to get only new statues that have been added since that last status..

Comment: You can keep adding the key references in and keep a date stamp, sorting by that date. This way you just keep coming back to a given user's entity and you'll have all of the info right there without querying. BUT, this will cost you in entity size and will probably need some sort of cleanup process to remove old keys from that collection. An RDBMS might be a better fit. If you don't have ancestral relationship between entities, GAE HRD's "eventual" consistency will become an issue. They use Paxos: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/structuring_for_strong_consistency

Comment: I'm happy to try and help further, but need to take this to a different discussion medium - comments weren't meant for long discussions on stackoverflow.com.